# Null pointer/array index out of bound/crazy exception in javafx with binding properties

Tags: java, multithreading, binding, javafx, javafx-8

I am trying out binding properties in javafx. I have a PieChart that has its data bind to changing properties. But i receive null pointer exception after a while, sometimes is ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, other times it won't start at all, it's crazy and erratic.

The ChartData class has 5 properties and 5 threads that periodically modify those properties in an effort to simulate real-time stream. The threads can be set with sleeping timer which i usually set to 50.

The Main2 class is the main javafx class, it has a PieChart, instance of ChartData that has its changing properties bind to PieChart properties.

It seems that the error is always in AbstractMasterTimer class. Can anyone give a hint on what is going on?

ChartData class:

```
package main;

import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class ChartData {

    private DoubleProperty pieProp1;
    private DoubleProperty pieProp2;
    private DoubleProperty pieProp3;
    private DoubleProperty pieProp4;
    private DoubleProperty pieProp5;

    public ChartData(){
        pieProp1 = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
        pieProp2 = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
        pieProp3 = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
        pieProp4 = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
        pieProp5 = new SimpleDoubleProperty();

        ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
        exec.submit(new PropertyGenerator(pieProp1));
        exec.submit(new PropertyGenerator(pieProp2));
        exec.submit(new PropertyGenerator(pieProp3));
        exec.submit(new PropertyGenerator(pieProp4));
        exec.submit(new PropertyGenerator(pieProp5));
    }

    public double getPieProp1(){return pieProp1.doubleValue();}
    public double getPieProp2(){return pieProp2.doubleValue();}
    public double getPieProp3(){return pieProp3.doubleValue();}
    public double getPieProp4(){return pieProp4.doubleValue();}
    public double getPieProp5(){return pieProp5.doubleValue();}

    public void setPieProp1(double v){pieProp1.set(v);}
    public void setPieProp2(double v){pieProp2.set(v);}
    public void setPieProp3(double v){pieProp3.set(v);}
    public void setPieProp4(double v){pieProp4.set(v);}
    public void setPieProp5(double v){pieProp5.set(v);}

    public DoubleProperty pieProp1(){return pieProp1;}
    public DoubleProperty pieProp2(){return pieProp2;}
    public DoubleProperty pieProp3(){return pieProp3;}
    public DoubleProperty pieProp4(){return pieProp4;}
    public DoubleProperty pieProp5(){return pieProp5;}

}

class PropertyGenerator implements Runnable{

    DoubleProperty prop;

    public PropertyGenerator(DoubleProperty prop){
        this.prop = prop;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        while(true){
            prop.set(Math.random() * 30);
//            System.out.println("qwe");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println(ex.toString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And now the main Main2 class:

```
package main;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.scene.chart.PieChart;

public class Main2 extends Application{

    @Override
    public void start (Stage s){
        PieChart pc = new PieChart();
        ObservableList<PieChart.Data> chartData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        chartData.add(new PieChart.Data("Dat1", 0.0));
        chartData.add(new PieChart.Data("Dat2", 0.0));
        chartData.add(new PieChart.Data("Dat3", 0.0));
        chartData.add(new PieChart.Data("Dat4", 0.0));
        chartData.add(new PieChart.Data("Dat5", 0.0));
        pc.setLegendVisible(false);

        ChartData cd = new ChartData();
        chartData.get(0).pieValueProperty().bindBidirectional(cd.pieProp1());
        chartData.get(1).pieValueProperty().bindBidirectional(cd.pieProp2());
        chartData.get(2).pieValueProperty().bindBidirectional(cd.pieProp3());
        chartData.get(3).pieValueProperty().bindBidirectional(cd.pieProp4());
        chartData.get(4).pieValueProperty().bindBidirectional(cd.pieProp5());

        pc.setData(chartData);

        Scene sc = new Scene(pc);

        s.setScene(sc);
        s.show();
    }
    public static void main (String[] args){
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UI properties may only be modified on the JavaFX application thread. In your example, the generated properties live on 5 different threads, while `pieValueProperty()` of `PieChart.Data` may only be modified on the JavaFX application thread.

Here is a working solution, using [ReactFX](https://github.com/TomasMikula/ReactFX) event streams as data sources.

```
import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.PieChart;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import org.reactfx.EventStream;
import org.reactfx.EventStreams;

class ChartData {
    private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler =
            Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    private final Executor executor = scheduler;

    EventStream<Double> pieProp1 = randomDoubleStream();
    EventStream<Double> pieProp2 = randomDoubleStream();
    EventStream<Double> pieProp3 = randomDoubleStream();
    EventStream<Double> pieProp4 = randomDoubleStream();
    EventStream<Double> pieProp5 = randomDoubleStream();

    private EventStream<Double> randomDoubleStream() {
        return EventStreams.ticks(Duration.ofMillis(100), scheduler, executor)
                .supply(() -> Math.random() * 30)
                .threadBridgeToFx(executor);
    }

    public void dispose() {
        scheduler.shutdown();
    }
}

public class AsyncChart extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage s){
        PieChart pc = new PieChart();
        ObservableList<PieChart.Data> chartData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        chartData.add(new PieChart.Data("Dat1", 0.0));
        chartData.add(new PieChart.Data("Dat2", 0.0));
        chartData.add(new PieChart.Data("Dat3", 0.0));
        chartData.add(new PieChart.Data("Dat4", 0.0));
        chartData.add(new PieChart.Data("Dat5", 0.0));
        pc.setLegendVisible(false);

        ChartData cd = new ChartData();
        cd.pieProp1.feedTo(chartData.get(0).pieValueProperty());
        cd.pieProp2.feedTo(chartData.get(1).pieValueProperty());
        cd.pieProp3.feedTo(chartData.get(2).pieValueProperty());
        cd.pieProp4.feedTo(chartData.get(3).pieValueProperty());
        cd.pieProp5.feedTo(chartData.get(4).pieValueProperty());

        pc.setData(chartData);

        Scene sc = new Scene(pc);

        s.setScene(sc);
        s.setOnHidden(evt -> cd.dispose());
        s.show();
    }

    public static void main (String[] args){
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

There are two important things to note about this code:

1. `executor` is a *single thread* executor. This is important, because just as JavaFX properties, ReactFX event streams are designed to be accessed from a single thread only. If you wanted the five streams to be generated by 5 different threads, you would need five *single thread* executors, one to generate each stream.
2. Note the `threadBridgeToFx(executor)` line. This returns a stream that mirrors the original stream (accessed from `executor`'s thread), but can be accessed from (and only from) the JavaFX application thread.

Comment: Are you sure? It looks like the threads are not changing UI properties, they are changing the `DoubleProperty`s in the `ChartData` which are bound to the UI properties.

Comment: Yeah, i am aware of that. I tried using javafx.concurrent libraries as well, but the results was the same. But even with this setup, it ran several times. Like said - it's erratic.

Besides that, UI is not modified directly due to the bounding principle, right?

Comment: Not sure if the error you are getting is due to threading, but I'm quite sure threading is not correct in the example. When you bind a property `p` to property `q`, then when `q` is updated, `p` is updated from the same thread as `q`.

Comment: @user2092119 I included a working solution in my answer.

Comment: Fascinating and disappointing - fascinating that there is a difference between five single-thread executors and one five-thread executor, are you able to expand on that? - disappointing that an inherently multi-threadable architecture like property binding still cannot handle multi-threaded use.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon The issue with five-thread executor is that it could result in 2 of its threads accessing a thread-unsafe object at the same time. If bindings in JavaFX were thread safe, then you would either 1) have the synchronization overhead and risk deadlocks, or 2) make all updates asynchronous which IMO would make their use much more complicated (e.g. no guarantees that two properties are in sync; _eventual consistency_ is the best you could get) and result in UI glitches.